# Simplifying an upper O-bound in two variables

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I have an algorithm that depends on two input sizes n and m. The complexity breaks down to the following equation:

$\frac{nm - 1}{n-1} = O(?)$

Is Big-O of the Formula $O(mn)$ or $O(m)$ because $n$ cancels out? Thank you in advance!

PS: I know that if $O(m)$ is the upper bound $O(mn)$ is an upper bound too, I want to find the tightest.

Comment: Landau bounds in two variables are tricky. Which one goes to infinity? Both? If so, in which way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that $n\ge 2$, which implies $1/(n-1)\le 2/n$. Then

$$ \frac{nm-1}{n-1} \le \frac{nm}{n-1} \le 2  \frac{nm}{n} \le 2m.   $$

Thus your expression is bounded by $O(m)$.

Comment: Thank you. Is $\frac{O(nm-1)}{O(n-1)} = \frac{O(nm)}{O(n)} = O(\frac{nm}{n}) = O(m)$ also a valid way to show this, or is that too "dirty"?

Comment: @user3158988: yes the $m$ was in the wrong way. The other way is indeed dirty: big-O is a set of functions - you cant divide two sets this way.

Answer (score 5):

Since we know nothing about the connection of $n$ and $m$ as the input size tends to infinity, we can only derive rough bounds.

Call your term

$\qquad f(n,m) = \frac{n}{n-1} \cdot m - \frac{1}{n-1}$.

Assuming $n > 1$, we have

$\qquad f(n,m) \leq 2m - \frac{1}{n-1}$

and

$\qquad f(n,m) \geq m - \frac{1}{n-1} $.

Therefore, $f(m,n) \in \Theta(m)$ as $n,m \to \infty$.

Note how very lucky you are here. It is usually *not* possible to get rid of one variable for such bounds without knowing how the two variables relate. In particular, make sure you understand why we can not just say "$n/(n-1) \to 1$, so $f(n,m) \sim m$".
*Hint:* What if $m/n \sim 1/\sqrt{n}$?

For more on asymptotics in two variables see e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/what-is-the-meaning-of-omn) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/is-omn-considered-linear-or-quadratic-growth).