# What kind of growth is $O(0.24\cdot K\cdot 2^w)$

Tags: terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

I've calculated the running time of an algorithm I'm interested in to be

$$O(0.24\cdot K\cdot 2^{w})\,,$$

where $K$ and $w$ are both variables.  ($K$ is the number of elements in some set, and $w$ is the log of the largest element, so both are variables.)

What kind of growth does this function have? I'll say it is exponential, however I don't know what the 0.24 implies.

Comment: Also, this question has nothing to do with time complexity. $O()$ is a notation for classes of functions. Those functions could be used to measure anything at all: the population of a bacterial colony, for example.

Comment: @David Richerby thank you for the edits, won't be a problem to disconnect edits from the answers? For instance I edited the question and now the answers are bit missaligned, on another stack* forums we chose this way of "version" a question to provide information about why people answered in a specific way, I'll stick to your suggestion anyway.

Comment: @JesusSalas The edit I made didn't disconnect because all it did was clarify. But your more recent edit has changed the question and people will wonder why all the answers are talking about $0.24K$ when the question says $K/4$...

Comment: 1) If you are about to change a question in a way that invalidates meaningful answers -- don't. Post a new question instead.  2) Versioning posts is useless since all revisions are kept, anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you know what exactly $O$ with two variables means?

Comment: @Raphael, no, I'm not sure what exactly O with two variables means, and this is why I asked the question, to learn more about these things, it would be great for everybody like me to get an explanation that can help understand this better, would you mind to help me (and others) understand what it means by pointing to an explanation/create one?

Comment: @David Richerby you are completely right, thanks for reverting back, this let the question be more consistent

Comment: @JesusSalas You may want to check out [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3149/98) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9523/98) question. Bottom line: few people know what they are doing when they use multi-parameter Landau notation.

Comment: @Raphael thank you so much, this helps a lot to understand what is the proper way to handle a two variables approach

Comment: In terms of [parametrized complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) it is fixed parameter linear.

Comment: @cardobard_box very interesting, thanks for sharing, as the time complexity under discussion belongs to an algorithm for a specific np-complete problem, then, that specific problem is FPL and belongs to the class FPT, and it has been previously classified as "W[1]-hard, in W[P]" by the Compendium of Parameterized Problems (http://www.sprg.uniroma2.it/home/cesati/research/compendium/compendium.pdf), I never listened anything about parametrized complexity I'm going to learn more about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is constant and $w$ is variable then $0.24\times K\times 2^w$ and the function is exponential in $w$, therefore it is $O(2^w)$.

If $K$ is variable and $w$ is constant then $0.24\times K\times 2^w$ is $O(K)$ - linear in $K$.

If both $K$  and $w$ are variables then $0.24\times K\times 2^w$ is $O(K2^w)$.

If both $K$  and $w$ are constant then $0.24\times K\times 2^w$ is $O(1)$.

The constant $0.24$ is ignored since it becomes irrelevant when we compare the rate of growth of a function. For more details please see [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

We also use $O^*(f(n))$ notation, in particular in analysis of parametrized algorithms, which means that the algorithm runs in 
$O(f(n)p(k))$ for some polynomial $p(k)$. So you could also write it is $O^*(2^w)$ in case $w$ is variable.

Comment: Ah, right , I didn't remember we eliminate constants in the BIG-O notation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(K,w) = K\cdot 2^w$ has polynomial (in fact, linear) dependence on $K$ and exponential dependence on $w$.

You're interested in the function $g(K,w) = 0.24\cdot f(K,w)$ but the constant multiplier doesn't change anything.  Linear growth in $K$ means that, if $K$ doubles, then $f(K,w)$ doubles, too. But doubling $K$ also doubles $g(K,w)$.  Exponential growth (with base $2$) means that adding $1$ to $w$ doubles $f(K,w)$, and the same applies to $g$.