# Interpretation of an asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics

Assume that we measure the complexity of an algorithm (for some problem) by two parameters $n$ and $m$ (where $m \le n$). What is the formal interpretation of the following claim: there is no algorithm that solves the given problem in $o(m + \log{n})$?

In particular, does it mean that an $O(\log{n})$ algorithm is possible?

Comment: Closely related reference questions: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3149/98, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9523/98

Comment: Basically, nobody really agrees on how to formally define and/or interpret multi-variable Landau notation; it doesn't really work the way we want it to. If your prof uses the notation, ask them for a formal definition (not how the one you were probably given for a single parameter doesn't immediately carry over!).

Comment: In any case, you'll have to fix the _cost measure_ for the statement to be meaningful. _Probably_ you mean "time"? In that case, the statement would translate to "the time-complexity of this problem is $\Omega(m + \log n)$, with the intended interpretation of that linear effort in $m$ is _required_, which would rule out $O( \log n)$-time algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

What this means is:

> For every algorithm solving the problem, it is *not* the case that the worst-case running time $T(m,n)$ in terms of $m,n$ satisfies the following property: for every $c > 0$ there is $m_0(c)$ such that for all $n \geq m \geq m_0(c)$,
>   $$ T(m,n) < c(m + \log n). $$

This doesn't rule out an $O(\log n)$ algorithm, since $\log n$ doesn't satisfy the property written above.

Comment: Let us further assume that when $m \le \log{n}$ there is no algorithm with $o(\log{n})$ time, and when $m \ge \log{n}$ there is no algorithm with $o(m)$ time. According to the above definition, this is not equivalent to saying that there is no $o(m+\log{n})$ algorithm. So what can we say about the complexity in this case? In many cases, I saw that this leads to a conclusion that there is no $o(m+\log{n})$ algorithm, or that any algorithm requires $\Omega(m+\log{n})$. What is the correct interpretation for such cases?

Comment: There is no single correct interpretation. When in doubt, check the proof to see what exactly is proved. If it is a conjecture or hypothesis, it ought to be spelled out in full.